# Trouble adding buttons to UITableViewCell in Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift, detailtextlabel

How can I add a UIButton into a UITableViewCell? I am having trouble doing this in Storyboards.

Comment: That's two completely unrelated questions. Ask one question at a time, please.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I believe I've updated my question to be a single question. By the way, I look forward to purchasing your upcoming book on Swift.

Comment: Actually for what you're doing my existing iOS 8 / Xcode 6 / Swift book would be more helpful! Your problem here is not Swift, it's your understanding of table view cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the only prototype cell style you can modify in Xcode is a Custom style. Make that setting in the cell's Attributes inspector and all will be well.

I made a little screencast that demonstrates: http://youtu.be/bN-nBOgFL00

Note that there are two different things about a cell that can be important here: its style (in the attributes inspector) and its class (in the identity inspector). They are totally different things and have no relation to one another (they are "orthogonal", as we like to say). Something you said earlier makes me think you may be confusing them with each other...!